# How can I bypass a command to terminal inside another terminal via python?

Tags: python, linux, bash, subprocess

In python, we can call any process using subprocess.

I have a situation where I have to work with interactive terminal where I need output of few commands, using python code.

How can I use subprocess module that will open the interactive terminal and I can further bypass few command and get their out to parse them further?

I am able to use subprocess module for 2 different command that where 2nd one is dependent on output of first one like

`ps -aux | grep python`

first `ps -aux` can be passed to 1 subprocess obj and that obj will be used as `stdin` of another subprocess command where `grep python` will be processed....

Answer (score 0):

you question is not much clear , so i would answer the part which i understand

How can I use subprocess module that will open the interactive terminal and I can further bypass few command and get their out to parse them further?

i have a ubuntu machine and this is the way i invoke a separate terminal and pass command to them

```
        from subprocess import Popen,PIPE
        command='who'
        command ='"'+command+' '+';read -n1" '
         #subitem = Popen(['gnome-terminal','--disable-factory','-x','bash','-c',command],stdin =PIPE)
          subitem = Popen(['gnome-terminal','--disable-factory','-x','bash'],stdin =PIPE)
        subitem.communicate(input='your command')
```

You can further play with this using stdin,stdout,communicate method depending on your requirment

Comment: The interactive terminal does not allow to pass commands to the terminal via arguments like you did. I can only enter the commands after entering into the terminal. It is a kind of command line utility/client actually...

Comment: Hi pankaj, that doesn't accepts in `subitem.communicate(input='your command')` this way.... :| :(